# Bluetooth and notification in web mobile apps

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications

Can a web mobile app interact with bluetooth features of the phone? Can a web app send notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Not without using something like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com) to bridge between the browser and native APIs.  That would allow you to develop most of the app as a web app (HTML5, JavaScript) and deploy it as an app with app features like Bluetooth.  There's no javascript interface via web browser to the Bluetooth hardware.

This is an example of a Phonegap bluetooth plug-in:

https://github.com/jimgeisler/phonegap-android-bluetooth-plugin-example